# Filtering questions by specifying multiple tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, filtering

The users should be allowed to view questions filtered by multiple tags. e.g. I want to see those questions which have tags "ruby-on-rails" and "cucumber" and "testing". It would be much better if we could be able to have an "or" modifier also just like "and".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This feature already exists, along with additional options for filtering based on multiple tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/).

#### Example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design+.net

As you click tags in the "related tags" area they'll be appended to the URL as above.

Comment: Cool thanks i didnt notice that

Comment: what if I want to combine the filters in OR ?

Comment: tag+tag not working for me - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150023/searching-for-multiple-tags-only-returns-some-of-the-matching-questions

Comment: As mentioned at that question, on the "faq" tab you may not see all of the questions. Switch to something like "newest".

Answer (score 1):

Just do a search for both tag names in brackets:   `[c#] [sql-server]`

Another option is to click on the c# tag and then on the sql-server tag in the list of related tags on the right.