# Can we filter on more than one tag at a time?

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filtering questions by specifying multiple tags.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9797/filtering-questions-by-specifying-multiple-tags)

I like the feature to look at a tag, but find it lacking when I further want to constrain the results, e.g.
select a tag on Design, get Java, .Net, Smalltalk... when I would like to see just Design + .Net