# Filter by multiple tags

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filtering questions by specifying multiple tags.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9797/filtering-questions-by-specifying-multiple-tags)

How can I filter the questions by multiple tags at once?

For example I want to filter the questions that contain c# and sql-server tags.