# View questions from more than one tag

Tags: feature-request, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filtering questions by specifying multiple tags.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9797/filtering-questions-by-specifying-multiple-tags)

On reddit.com you can view multiple subreddits by appending them in the address bar like this:
http://www.reddit.com/r/**technology+programming**

Can we have that here?

**Clarification:**
Needs to bring up matches to either tag1 OR tag2.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/**jquery+javascript**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery+javascript)

Comment: But it only brings up questions that have both tags , not either tag1 OR tag2

Comment: @user152499, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery+OR+javascript