# set a favorite/personal tag view for questions on stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tab for questions that are labelled with interesting or favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labelled-with-interesting-or-favorite-tags)

Oftentimes when I want to try and answer the latest questions, I click on the questions tab and it shows all the questions from all categories. I'm almost always interested in say only 3 or 4 tags related to my domain. I see that I can add favorite tags but there is no way to show all the questions belonging to my favorite tags only. I end up having to click on each tag one at a time and view the questions, try to answer them and click the other one etc. It would be nice to have a feature where I could group my tags and view all asked questions belonging to only them.

I understand from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9797/filtering-questions-by-specifying-multiple-tags) that I can keep clicking on the related tags or search for multiples together but it is nice not to have to do this every time.